# Keep excel offset within worksheet

Tags: excel, offset

I have a table like this:

```
Length  4           

year    1   2   3   4   5

A      100 400 300 200 400

B
```

And in column B I want a sum of A from the past [length] years. For this I figured I needed an OFFSET, so my function is (for year 2):

=SUM.IF(OFFSET(B3;0;0;1;-B1);">0")

The if statement is used so it doesn't give an error when it reaches the edge of the table, but for years 2 and 3 the OFFSET range is outside of the worksheet so it doesn't work. How can I specify a condition that it just doesn't sum anything that isn't on the worksheet?

Comment: Hi,


I'm sorry I'm not very familiar here. But This is just in in excel so no further language... 

The values I want are in column B, and it's for years 2, 3, 4 and 5: 100, 500, 800, 1000 respectively. (and If I were to add another year it should be 1300, because the length is only 4). 

But I want this range to be dynamic (to be changeable through Length), but then the range drops off the worksheet.

Answer (score 1):

In A2:

`=SUM(INDEX(1:1,COLUMNS($A:A)):INDEX(1:1,MAX(1,COLUMNS($A:A)-3)))`

Copy to the right as required.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it was hard to decypher the question:
When you ask column B, I guess you mean *row* 4, right?

1. You don't need SUMIF, because SUM doesn't count empty cells or cells
   with non-numeric value.
2. The reference to the length value should be absolute, so it doesn't
   change as you copy the formula: 
   *`$B$1`*
3. OFFSET's Width value cannot be negative, rather have the Cols value =
   -[Length]: 
   `OFFSET(C3;0; -`*`$B$1`*... 
   (Now you are referencing 4 columns left to C3)
4. Make sure it is not out of the worksheet by not letting more than the [column number of the given cell minus 1] be referenced left from the cell: 
   `OFFSET(C3;0; -`*`MIN(COLUMN(C3)-1;$B$1)`*...
5. That is the starting point of your range to sum; you should sum it
   up to recent year's value. So the correct formula in C4 is:

   `=SUM(OFFSET(C3;0;-MIN(COLUMN(C3)-1;$B$1)):C3)`

Comment: Yeah I'm sorry I wasn't very clear, but this is perfect!

Comment: @FolmerFerment please upvote and/or accept the answer(s) you like. Thank you.